# Maximum Likelihood Estimators from two normal populations

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, variance, maximum-likelihood

I've been struggling with this challenge in my notes for a while:

> Suppose I have a sample of size *n* taken from each of: 
>   $X_1 \sim N(a+b,\sigma^2)$ and $X_2 \sim N(a-b,\sigma^2)$ where $a, b > 0$.
>
> The sample observations are denoted $x_{ij}$ , $i = 1, 2$ and $j = 1, . . . , n$.
>
> What are the maximum likelihood estimators of $a$, $b$ and $\sigma^2$?

(Edit: Having now observed the rules of the forum, I'm sorry for having asked this question so broadly and I should have noted where my issues lay and for more general advice.)

My issue here is where to start since I had the idea to set $a+b$ as $\mu_1$ and $a-b$ as $\mu_2$, but I have no idea how to then use $\hat{\mu_1}$ and $\hat{\mu_2}$ to find $\hat{a}$ and $\hat{b}$.

Comment: For homework assignments add the [tag:self-study] tag and review the site criteria on such questions. Mainly: explain what you've tried and where are you confused?

Comment: Another way to approach this is to define $\mu_1 = a+b$ and $\mu_2 = a-b$. The MLE's for $\mu_i$ are well known and easily obtainable. Then we can use the Invariance property to obtain $\hat a$ and $\hat b$. Although it's a little unclear how to incorporate the requirement that $a,b > 0$ here.

Comment: Hint: the MLE estimator of any nice function of the parameters is the same function of their MLE estimates.  Thus, for instance, the MLE of $a=(\mu_1+\mu_2)/2$ is $(\hat\mu_1+\hat\mu_2)/2$.

Comment: Do you know which observation comes from which distribution?

Answer (score 1):

Since this could possibly be a homework problem, I'm not going to write a full solution.

1. Step 1: Write the joint distribution of observing the samples of $X_1$
       and $X_2$. If we see this as a function of a, b, and $\sigma^2$,
       then, we call it the likelihood function. Take the log of this expression to get log-likelihood. MLE is searching the values of a, b, and $\sigma^2$ that maximize the likelihood, and hence, the log-likelihood.
2. Step 2: Differentiate the log-likelihood with respect to a and b, and equate 
   to zero. We are trying to find values of a and b which
   maximize the likelihood of observing the samples, so, we use the
   stationarity of first-order differential at maximum.  This would
   give you $a=\dfrac{\sum_i x_{1,i}+\sum_i x_{2,i}}{2n}$ and
   $b=\dfrac{\sum_i x_{1,i}-\sum_i x_{2,i}}{2n}$.
3. Step 3: Differentiate the log-likelihood with respect
   $\sigma^2$. This would give you $\sigma^2=\dfrac{\sum_i
   (x_{1,i}-\bar{x_1})^2+\sum_i (x_{2,i}-\bar{x_2})^2}{2n}$ where
   $\bar{x_j}=\dfrac{\sum_i x_{j,i}}{n}$.
4. PS: As pointed out in the comment, we need to incorporate the constraints $a, b\gt 0$ into the likelihood maximization. So instead of maximizing $\mathcal{LL}$ (log-likelihood), we maximize $\mathcal{LL}+\dfrac{\lambda}{\sigma^2} a +\dfrac{\nu}{\sigma^2} b$ where $\lambda$, and $\nu$ are unknown. I have added the $\sigma^2$ to $\lambda$ and $\nu$ terms to simplify the solution. The new solutions will be $a=\dfrac{\sum_i x_{1,i}+\sum_i x_{2,i}-\lambda}{2n}$, $b=\dfrac{\sum_i x_{1,i}-\sum_i x_{2,i}-\nu}{2n}$ and $\sigma^2=\dfrac{\sum_i
   (x_{1,i}-(a+b))^2+\sum_i (x_{2,i}-(a-b))^2}{2n}$. If a or b without the constriant is less than zero, we equate it to zero by giving a non-zero value to $\lambda$ or $\nu$.

Comment: nice job, but ... you've left out the constraints on $a$ and $b$, which are important.  To simplify life, you might want to rewrite the constraints as $a, b \geq 0$ rather than $a, b > 0$ and explain why that's necessary.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! I should have been careful.