# Maximum likelihood estimator and minimum variance challenge

Tags: normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood, minimum-variance

A random sample of size $n_1$ is to be drawn from a normal population with mean $\mu_1$ and variance $\sigma^2_1$.

A second random sample of size $n_2$ is to be drawn from a normal
population with mean $\mu_2$ and variance $\sigma^2_2$. The two samples are independent.

What is the maximum likelihood estimator of $α = \mu_1 − \mu_2$?
 Assuming that the total
sample size $n = n_1 + n_2$ is fixed, how should the $n$ observations be divided between
the two populations in order to minimise the variance of $\hatα$?

Comment: The first part is essentially the same as your recent question at  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/314287/maximum-likelihood-estimators-from-two-normal-populations.

Comment: Should be equally distributed, that is a simple calculus exercise.